# Cython, CMake and setup.py, python in a subdirectory compiles twice

Tags: python, cmake, cython, setup.py

I'm trying to build a C++ library together with Cython bindings following the structure of https://bloerg.net/2012/11/10/cmake-and-distutils.html.

The issue is that during `make install`, the extension will be compiled twice. This double compilation does not happen when there is only one main `CMakeLists.txt` in the main folder (with paths adjusted). Here are the details:

My project structure is

```
.
├── CMakeLists.txt
├── python
│   ├── CMakeLists.txt
│   ├── a_py.pxd
│   ├── a_py.pyx
│   └── setup.py.in
└── src
    ├── A.cpp
    └── A.h
```

The top level `CMakeLists.txt` only contains `add_subdirectory(python)`.

`python/CMakeLists.txt` is

```
IF(NOT ${PYTHON})
    find_program(PYTHON "python")
ENDIF()

set(SETUP_PY_IN "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/setup.py.in")
set(SETUP_PY    "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/setup.py")

set(PY_OUTPUT      "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/build/pytimestamp")

configure_file(
    ${SETUP_PY_IN}
    ${SETUP_PY}
)

add_custom_command(OUTPUT "${PY_OUTPUT}"
                   COMMAND ${PYTHON} ${SETUP_PY} build_ext
                   COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E touch ${PY_OUTPUT}
               )

add_custom_target(a_py ALL DEPENDS ${PY_OUTPUT})

install(CODE "execute_process(COMMAND ${PYTHON} ${SETUP_PY} install)")
```

`setup.py` is:

```
from distutils.core import setup
from distutils.extension import Extension
from Cython.Distutils import build_ext
ext_modules = [
    Extension(
    name="a",
    sources=["${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/a_py.pyx", "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../src/A.cpp"],
    include_dirs = ['${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../src'],
    language="c++",
    ),
]
setup(
    name = 'a',
    version='${PROJECT_VERSION}',
    cmdclass = {'build_ext': build_ext},
    ext_modules = ext_modules,
    package_dir={ 'a': '${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}' },
)
```

In both cases (`CMakeFile.txt` in root or in `python` subfolder), first the `build_ext` step runs:

> ```
> Scanning dependencies of target a_py
> [100%] Generating build/pytimestamp
> running build_ext
> ```

and compiles the generated `a_py.cpp` and `A.cpp` and links the library.
During the install step, the compilation is run again *only when `CMakeFile.txt` is in the `python` subfolder*.

This is what happens during installation:

> ```
> running build_ext
> skipping '/Users/xxx/tmp/ctest/t08/python/a_py.cpp' Cython extension (up-to-date)
> building 'a' extension
> creating build
> ```

Note that the `a_py.pyx` does not get cythonized again, but the build directory gets recreated (it is the same between the build and install steps) and the files are compiled (with exactly the same compiler and linker invocations).

A full example can be found here: https://github.com/zeeMonkeez/cmakeCythonTest

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. Apparently, in my case, during the install phase `setup.py` had trouble finding the directory where it put the compiled extensions in the build phase, so it recompiled them even with the `--skip-build` switch.

I solved by specifying the same directory path at both build and install phases with the `--build-lib` and `--build-dir` switches respectively:

```
    add_custom_command(OUTPUT ${PY_OUTPUT}
            COMMAND ${PYTHON} ${SETUP_PY} build_ext --build-lib ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/mysoext
            COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E touch ${PY_OUTPUT}
            DEPENDS ${DEPS}
            )
...
        set(MYINSTCMD "\
            EXECUTE_PROCESS(COMMAND ${PYTHON} ${SETUP_PY} install_lib \
            --skip-build \
            --install-dir /my/install/dir \
            --build-dir ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/mysoext)")
        install(CODE "${MYINSTCMD}")
```